# Error on calling Task.Run to create an async process

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, xamarin, async-await

I've been reviewing the code an app dev company has been doing for me in Xamarin. When I try to compile

```
namespace AppName.Droid         
public class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity
{

    protected override void OnStart ()
    {
        base.OnStart ();

        Task.Run (Login);
    }

    async void Login()
    {
        await LoadCurrentProfile().ContinueWith(result => {
            if (ApplicationState.Profile== null)
            {
                GoLogin ();
            }
            else
            {
                GoBegin ();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

There is an error on "Task.Run(Login)" that

```
'void SplashActivity.Login()' has the wrong return type
```

Is there something that I can change so that I can compile the app on my machine?

Comment: Let `Login` return `Task` instead of `void`.

Comment: Why are you using `Task.Run`? Do you want to fire and forget? What do you expect to happen if `Login` threw an exception?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Yacoub! Your answer works very well for my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the signature of `Login` to return a `Task` like this:

```
async Task Login()
{
    //...
}
```

And call it like this:

```
Task.Run( (Func<Task>) Login);
```

or

```
Task.Run(() => Login());
```

Please note that since `Login` is an asynchronous method, you can also call it directly without using `Task.Run` like this (I am assuming that you want to fire and forget):

```
Login();
```

Answer (score 4):

There's several things wrong with your approach to `async`. I recommend you read my [`async` intro blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) and [`async` best practices article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

In particular, you should follow these conventions:

- Don't use `ContinueWith`. Use `await` instead.
- Avoid `async void`. Use `async Task` unless you *have* to use `async void`.
- Use `Task.Run` to push CPU-bound work off the UI thread. In the case of your code, there's no reason to use `Task.Run`.

Combining these, the code is quite simplified, and also has more reasonable semantics (in particular, login errors are not silently ignored):

```
protected override async void OnStart ()
{
  base.OnStart();
  await LoginAsync();
}

async Task LoginAsync()
{
  await LoadCurrentProfile();
  if (ApplicationState.Profile == null)
  {
    GoLogin();
  }
  else
  {
    GoBegin();
  }
}
```